# Given a list of username, do an update on all of them at once using Pymongo

Tags: python, pymongo

If I am given a list of username, and i want to update a particular field, how do I do it from this

```
for name in username:
    db.users.update({'name': username}, {'$set': {"status" :"funny"}})
```

to a single line update on all usernames?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The precise answer depends on which version of MongoDB you are using (the syntax for `update` has changed), however the key is to set `multi` to `true`, which will update all documents that match the query. In this case, your query could be an array of usernames with which you would use the `$in` operator.

- [Update Multiple Documents](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/update/#update-multiple-documents)
- [`$in` operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/in/)

Answer (score 0):

In mongodb shell,

`db.users.update({name:{$in:username}},{$set:{'field':'value'}}, {multi: true})`

almost the same in pymongo ? not?